# 2016 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair's [first moderator election](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2] [image: DucatiKiller] [image: Bob Cross]

They'll be replacing [the existing crew](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, join me in thanking the moderators who served [during the beta period](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/moderator-pro-tem-announcement).

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/recount/5639636084850688/0).

Answer (score 13):

Thanks Jon!

I appreciate the confidence of getting the vote. This truly means a lot to me. I will endeavor to never let that trust be lost.

Thanks to @MoveMoreCommentsLinksToTop - Larry ... Appreciate all you've done for the site and sticking in there during the lean years.

Thanks to @MarkJohnson - Appreciate your service.

Special thanks to @BobCross - Looks like we're stuck with you ... It's alright. We likes yah! I look forward to working with you and @DucatiKiller. I especially look forward to your tutelage ... I'm going to need it!

Comment: Congratulations Paully!!

Comment: Congrats! Just remember what community moderated means. ;)

Comment: @JasonC - yes, it means the ban hammer for Jason C! J/K! Thanks :o)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 It means we're the mods, and you're our plan B when we can't get the job done. It's up to you to have the new community's back, even if the site changes from what you're used to now that we're out of beta. :)

Comment: @JasonC - I think I have a clue. I've got Ducati and Bob to ensure I do. And the a whole core of Mods beyond that ... it's a brave new world.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks everyone!
I'm really touched to see that you didn't launch me into the Sun at the first opportunity.  I guess I'm making an acceptable number of mistakes....  ;-)

Comment: I'm glad you're with us, Bob. Your experience will go far in training a couple of wrench monkeys like Paul and I to understand the job.

Comment: Congrats Bob I'm glad you're back for more!

Answer (score 8):

Well done you three - an excellent moderator team! Good to have the continuity from Bob, with some awesome new blood with technical knowledge in the form of Paulster2 and DucatiKiller.

Comment: Thanks Rory. Glad you're out there to give us Mod advice as well.

Comment: Don't worry man. We'll make our own Mechanics.SE. With blackjack and 2-stroke engines.

Comment: Heh - blackjack engines

Answer (score 7):

A bit late, I know, but I want to chime in with the others and say a hearty congratulations to three groups.

## 1. The pro-tems

I want to say a warm thank-you to Larry and Bob for the work that they have done keeping this thing going.  You have devoted many hours over the past 5 1/2 years to keeping this site not only on its feet, but constantly advancing toward the place where we are now.  Your efforts are greatly appreciated!

## 2. The new moderators

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 ♦, @Bob Cross ♦, @DucatiKiller ♦, I am thrilled to see you as our moderators.  I feel quite confident that you will serve the site well, as it continues to move forward.  I want to congratulate you on your success, but also in advance on the work that you will put in in the future.

## 3. The other candidates

I know I fit in this category, but honestly, as I look at the other candidates, I do not see one any but that I would have loved having them as moderators as well.  @MoveMoreCommentsLinkToTop, @Zaid, @NickC, @RoryAlsop, @tlhIngan, you have done an excellent job.  You have served the community in many ways already: Keep up the good work!

We have a bright future here at mechanics.stackexchange.com.  The fair moon is setting, it is true, on our beta existence, but in its place the sun is rising in beautiful resplendence on a glorious new future as a fully graduated site.  We look forward to years of excellent material - questions and answers - that will build the community and enhance the internet world of mechanics.

Comment: Thanks @anonymous We have big shoes to fill and I'm thankful bobcross will be staying on and providing direction.